# How to find a parent node using recursion

Tags: c#, sorting, tree, nodes

I have an class like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
{
    ChildEntities = new List<Entity>();
}
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentNode { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; } //Level it is in the tree

    public List<Entity> ChildEntities { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of entities and I need to add each entity into its parent's collection of entities. To do this, I have tried to write a recursive function to find the parent node and return it. It looks something like this:

```
//Recursively find the parent node 
            Entity findParent(Entity rootEntity)
            {
                foreach (var entity in primaryEntity.ChildEntities)
                {
                    var foundParent = false;
                    if (entity.EntityName == rootEntity.ImmediateParent)
                    {
                        return entity;
                    }
                    if (entity.ChildEntities.Count != 0)
                    {
                        findParent(entity);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
```

I keep getting a stack overflow exception. What is the best practise to for this exercise and how should I do it?

Comment: Where do `.EntityName` and `.ImmediateParent` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is ok except you should be returning in your second if :

```
if (entity.ChildEntities.Count != 0)
{
   var parent = findParent(entity); // <- here
   if(parent != null){
     return parent;
   }
}
```

If this doesn't fix your problem. Then you must have some cycles in your tree.